# Why does the laplace transform of sine and cosine looks the way they are

Tags: laplace-transform

I always forget what the Laplace transform of sine and cosine looks like. This is because they look so similar to each other.

Does there exist a good mnemonic for remembering what form each takes? Or rather a good logical basis as to why each function takes the form that it does?

Comment: Express sine and cosine in terms of the complex exponential.